# how can i decode this base64 code?

Tags: md5, asp.net, base64, hashcode

im sorry if this is a stupid question but i was curious, i have this code that translates into my name im wondering what hash function its using, i thought it was `md5`

this is my name:

`saleh`

and this is the code

`9LjZ6QoOB1A%253d`

pleaaase help

Comment: Do you have a link to the encoder?

Comment: what do you mean, its used in aspx i think, it was apart of a link i.e. `view.aspx?lastname=9LjZ6QoOB1A%253d`

Comment: How/where did you get this string?

Comment: md5 hashes are normally represented in hex; if it contains characters other than 0-9 and a-f, it's not md5.  The last 2 characters are '=' urlencoded twice, which makes it look like Base64, but it doesn't decode as text.

Comment: yeh i tried decoding using base64 but its gives different results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely not MD5 -- MD5 output always consists of 32 hexadecimal characters.